# Communication with ADXL355 using SPI

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, spi

When communicating with the ADXL355 accelerometer from a Raspberry Pi, i2c works perfectly. However, when I try using SPI the register addresses don't match those in the manual and I need to understand why.

For example, the following code prints the results back from sending 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 and 0x03 which according to the manual (and what I experience when I use i2c) should correspond to DEVID_AD, DEVID_MST, PARTID, and REVID.

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void transfer(char charToTransfer)
{
    char buffer[] = { charToTransfer, 0x00};
    bcm2835_spi_transfern(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Rx:  %02X \n", buffer[1]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!bcm2835_init())
        return 1;

    bcm2835_spi_begin();
    bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
    bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);
    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_256);
    bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0); 
    bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);

    transfer(0x00);
    transfer(0x01);
    transfer(0x02);
    transfer(0x03);

    bcm2835_spi_end();

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is

```
Rx:  00 
Rx:  AD 
Rx:  00 
Rx:  1D
```

whereas it should be

```
Rx:  AD 
Rx:  1D 
Rx:  ED 
Rx:  01
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as at the moment I can't get data from the accelerometer until I understand why this simple communication isn't working.

Comment: Did you select the correct clock polarity and phase shift.

Comment: If the master transmits data it simultaneously receives data from the client. So you can not read the result of your cmd directly after transmission. So send the initial cmd and waste the result. Send the next cmd while receiving the data from the previous cmd. And so on

Comment: I believe so. The manual says that the CPOL = 0 and CPHA = 0.

Comment: Why are you only printing the second received byte? Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: That's why I send a buffer with length 2 - the first for the register and the second for the result. Each time, the second index in the buffer array is printed.

Comment: @DerekNash: But you are sending two bytes then each time?

Comment: The transmit buffer has 2 chars, one with the register and a dummy char to receive the result.

Comment: @DerekNash: [I don't think that's correct](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__spi.html#ga06884e9cd71dfe380f846b09f47b7248). "len - number of bytes in the buffer, and **the number of bytes to send** (...)", "The returned data from the slave **replaces** the transmitted data in the buffer". So I would read `bcm2835_spi_transfern(buff, 2)` as "send two bytes, and then write the response into this same buffer, starting from the beginning".

Comment: If you need to send and receive a single byte, perhaps it would be simpler to use [`uint8_t bcm2835_spi_transfer(uint8_t value)`](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/group__spi.html#ga600dc972f1064908b41b349c92d7647d), which just returns that one byte?

Comment: When I use a single byte I get no response back. The only way I have been able to receive data back from the device is to send a 2 length buffer where the response is written into the second byte. I understand that this is because it immediately transmits the response, so once the first byte is read, the second byte is then overwritten with the response. I am getting responses this way, its just that the register addresses don't match.

Comment: The responses seem to be out by a factor of 2. For example, if I do transfer(0x05) I get the response from the 0x02 register, and if I do transfer(0x07) I get the response from the 0x03 register.

Comment: @DerekNash: Print both bytes and you'll see that you're misinterpreting the results: `printf("Rx:  %02X %02X \n", buffer[0], buffer[1]);`

Comment: If I now do transfer(0x00) to 0x07 I get the following:
Rx:  00 00 
Rx:  00 AD 
Rx:  00 00 
Rx:  00 1D 
Rx:  00 00 
Rx:  00 ED 
Rx:  00 00 
Rx:  00 01 The first char is always 00, and where I do get a response on the second byte it's out from the expected result by a factor of 2 - so instead of 0, 1, 2, 3 it's on 1, 3, 5, and 7.

Comment: Are you sure your SPI is set to 8 bit mode? try using uint8_t  bcm2835_spi_transfer (uint8_t value) instead of bcm2835_spi_transfern (char *buf, uint32_t len)

Comment: Isn't that a single byte transfer? If so, I get nothing back. The manufacturer has confirmed I need to send the dummy byte in the transmit array with every transfer to receive the result - so it has to be a 2 byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies with the fact that bit 0 tells the device whether it's read or write. I'm not familiar with the notation of the bar above the W (feel free to correct me), but from my results I guess it has to be a 1 for read, which is why 0x00 became 0x01, 0x01 became 0x03, 0x02 became 0x05 etc as the register address needs to be shifted up 1 bit to allow for the RW bit.

[ADXL355 SPI Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBwjw.png)

In case it's helpful to anyone else, by changing the transfer function as shown below the registers now match up:

```
void transfer(char charToTransfer, int read)
{
    char buffer[] = { (charToTransfer << 1) + read , 0x00};
    bcm2835_spi_transfern(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if(read)
    {
        printf("Rx:  %02X \n", buffer[1]);
    }
}
```